# SSH tunneling for MySQL with multiple hops, without having user accounts on the MySQL end?

Tags: mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'd like to create several ssh tunnels to MySQL servers that are several hops away. I have ssh access to every server ***except*** the MySQL ones.

Here's how my setup looks like:

```
[desktop]=====[server]---------[mysql01]
                      \--------[mysql02]
                       \-------[mysql03]
                        \------[mysql04]
```

Currently, I can simply ssh into `[server]` and use `mysql -h mysql01 -u something -p` to establish a connection. Now, I want to create a tunnel for each of the MySQL servers so I can access them via a GUI on `[desktop]`. However, using `ssh -L` requires a user account on those MySQL servers, which I don't have.

Any ideas on how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could tunnel the Ports to your server.

```
ssh -L 3306:mysql01:3306 server
```

if you connect to server:3306 you end up on mysql01

Whats keeping you from entering mysql01 on the desktop gui?

Comment: That's the whole point! I need to be able to login to `mysql01` to execute your command. I can't do that, because I don't have an account on that machine.

Comment: no you don't need an account on mysql01. you need one on server which proxies to mysql01

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get how that would work. Could you type a complete example which routes `mysql01:3306` to, say, `desktop:8890`?

Comment: the linux desktop example is [ssh -L 8890:mysql01:3306 server] On windows it would be in putty Connection->SSH->Tunnels: Source: 8890 Destination: mysql01:3306 [x]local [x]auto and then connect so [server]

Comment: Aaargh! Thanks, I somehow thought I would need two separate tunnels, one on `server`, one on `desktop`. Excuse my stupidity, I'm not fully awake yet.